# vim script: how to execute a command in a vim function

Tags: vim

Why does the following:

```
let s:colorschemes = ['synic', 'ir_black']
let s:colorscheme_idx = 0

function! RotateColorscheme()
  let s:colorscheme_idx += 1
  let s:name = s:colorschemes[s:colorscheme_idx]
  echo s:name
  colorscheme s:name
endfunction
```

not execute the `colorscheme`? Vim complains with the following error 'cannot find colorschem s:name'. How do I tell it that I want it to derefence that variable and not apply it literally to :colorscheme?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at this script from [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes) which does pretty much what you are asking for.

Key-line seems to be this one:

```
let nowcolors = 'elflord morning desert evening pablo'
  execute 'colorscheme '.split(nowcolors)[i]
```

Comment: thanks but do you know why i need to use execute? I didn't need to use execute for the echo line above it? What makes :echo different from :colorscheme?

Comment: see `:help exe` vs. `:help echo`