# Is it possible to use <C-R>= with a VIM command?

Tags: vim

I have the following:

```
map  <F6> :SCCompile<cr>
map! <F6> <c-r>=SingleCompile#Compile()<cr>
```

I'd like to use `:SCCompile` in the second mapping too, is that possible?

Currently I have another command which I really don't want to wrap in a function call. I use `<c-r>=` in insert mode because it doesn't create undo points and it aways works good except for this limitation.

I've tried [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597249/vim-script-how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-vim-function) but it's not working.

Comment: You almost always want to use `noremap` instead of `remap`. If you use remap you'll break your settings horribly one day. See [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
map  <F6> :SCCompile<cr>
map! <F6> <c-r>=feedkeys("<c-o>:SCCompile\<lt>cr>")?'':''<cr>
```

The command isn't the simplest:

- here we ask Vim to execute some keys after leaving `<c-r>=`
- use `<lt>` to allow expanding of `<cr>` in command-line mode instead of in `<c-r>=`
- use `?:` operator to ignore value returned by `feedkeys()` function

See `:help feedkeys()`.

Comment: What is the benefit over directly using `<C-o>`? Chico wanted to avoid `<C-o>` because it creates an undo point.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I didn't really see `<C-o>` creating undo points in both cases (I tried `:undolist`). For me two commands above written that way just to reduce code duplication with limitation that the second one should use `<c-r>=`. But if it's the same as using `<C-o>` directly, why was it accepted?

Comment: For me, `:undolist` shows `N changes`, where N > 1; also, `u` removes entered text bit by bit.

Comment: @IngoKarkat strange, but I see the same number of changes even when running vim with `-u NONE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can built on my answer from your recent [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686210/vim-single-compile-command-from-insert-mode). It's exactly the same issue: Like `:call`, a custom Vim command doesn't return anything, but `<C-R>` requires an expression that returns something:

```
function! SingleCompileWrapper()
    SCCompile
    return ''
endfunction

map! <F6> <C-R>=SingleCompileWrapper()<CR>
```

Comment: I really don't want to write a wrapper as I have said.